# get_post_meta() returning an arrary when it shouldn't

Tags: php, wordpress

Why would using `get_post_meta()` all of a sudden start returning an array when `$single` is set to true?

```
$sync = get_post_meta( $pid, '_subscription_sync', true );
if ( 'yes' != $sync )
    return;
```

`var_dump($sync)` returns this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "yes" }`

Is there a global setting I'm not aware off?

Comment: There is no global setting and under this context it doesn't make sense. the 3rd argument to `get_post_meta()` dictates whether you get an array back or a string, so there shouldn't be any reason you're getting an array. Can you try with `get_metadata`? (which this is just a wrapper for) and replicate ?

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, it's completely bonkers.
Used `get_metadata` set to true and it's still an array.
I have install the plugins on another domain on the same hosing account and it's returning as a string.
Baffled.

Comment: if you are doing in post loop then, this this before getting meta ` global $post;`

Comment: How is the meta value saved into the database table? Are you saving an array or a string there?

Comment: I've just this second looked and it's serialised. http://screencast.com/t/F4izx73WgNK
Completely different to the other entries.
It's very weird how it starts off ok but then it does this.

Answer (score 0):

you have saved a array into the database. update_post_meta automatically serializes this for you. The $single setting on get_post_meta refers whether to pull all the entries with that post id and key..

Var_dump the variable you are saving just before update_post_meta and then check how it is ending up as a array.